# Permanently change PATH in Dockerfile with dynamic value

Tags: docker

I am using security scan software in my Dockerfile and I need to add its bin folder to the path. Its path will contain the version part so I do not know the path until I download the software. My current progress is something like this:

1.Download the software:

```
RUN curl https://cloud.appscan.com/api/SCX/StaticAnalyzer/SAClientUtil?os=linux --output SAClientUtil.zip
RUN unzip SAClientUtil.zip -d SAClientUtil
```

2.The desired folder is located: SAClientUtil/SAClientUtil.X.Y.Z/bin/ (xyz mary vary from run to run). Get there using find and cd combination and try to add it to the PATH:

```
RUN cd "$(dirname "$(find SAClientUtil -type f -name appscan.sh | head -1)")"; \
    export PATH="$PATH:$PWD"; # doesn't work
```

Looks like ENV command is not evaluating the parameter, so

```
ENV PATH $PATH:"echo $(dirname "$(find SAClientUtil -type f -name appscan.sh | head -1)")"
```

doesn't work also.
Any ideas on how to dynamically add a folder to the PATH during docker image build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're pretty sure the zip file will contain only a single directory with that exact layout, you can rename it to something fixed.

```
RUN curl https://cloud.appscan.com/api/SCX/StaticAnalyzer/SAClientUtil?os=linux --output SAClientUtil.zip \
 && unzip SAClientUtil.zip -d tmp \
 && mv tmp/SAClientUtil.* SAClientUtil \
 && rm -rf tmp SAClientUtil.zip
ENV PATH=/SAClientUtil/bin:${PATH}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to include a small wrapper script in your image, and then use that to run commands from the SAClientUtil directory.  For example, if I have the following in `saclientwrapper.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

cmd=$1
shift

saclientpath=$(ls -d /SAClientUtil/SAClientUtil.*)
echo "got path: $saclientpath"

cd "$saclientpath"
exec "$saclientpath/bin/$cmd" "$@"
```

Then I can do this:

```
RUN curl https://cloud.appscan.com/api/SCX/StaticAnalyzer/SAClientUtil?os=linux --output SAClientUtil.zip
RUN unzip SAClientUtil.zip -d SAClientUtil

COPY saclientwrapper.sh /saclientwrapper.sh

RUN sh /saclientwrapper.sh appscan.sh
```

And this will produce, when building the image:

```
STEP 6: RUN sh /saclientwrapper.sh appscan.sh
got path: /SAClientUtil/SAClientUtil.8.0.1374
COMMAND SYNTAX
        appscan <command> [options]
ADDITIONAL COMMAND HELP
        appscan help <command>

.
.
.
```